# Using .blank? with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Hi chaps and chappettes.

```
          <tbody>
            <% @orders_outstanding.limit(5).each do |order| %>
              <% if order.completed_at.blank? && order.due_date.present? %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= order.order_number %></td>
                  <td><%= order.customer %></td>
                  <td><%= order.printer %></td>
                  <td><%= order.quantity %></td>
                  <td><%= order.due_date %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
```

I'm using this little bit of code to display my next five orders due to ship. It's showing up in my development environment preview (puma/sqlite) but not on heroku (postgres). Is there any reason heroku doesn't like that formatting?

Thanks

Comment: Just to add, the title is as it is because the .blank? was the only thing I could see was different to my working code to show the most recent five orders to have shipped

Comment: What do you mean "not on heroku"? No orders are displayed on heroku? And you do have orders in the database? If you enter `Order.where(completed_at: nil).where.not(due_date: nil)` into the heroku console, do you get any results?

Comment: Yeah I get results in the console, the orders are definitely there. When I say not on heroku I mean the deployed app won't display the upcoming orders in the table as it should.

Comment: Does "as it should" mean they're not displaying at all? or its displaying something else unexpected? How is `@orders_outstanding` assigned?

Comment: It's defined in the controller as @orders_outstanding = Order.all.reorder("due_date"). 'As it should' meaning it's not displaying anything at all

Comment: Why don't you filter by completed_at/due_date in the controller? e.g. `Order.where(completed_at: nil).where.not(due_date: nil).order("due_date")`?

Comment: Metaphorical hole in the foot might be a good way to remember not to do it again! Putting the filter into the controller seems to have been the fix, thanks eirikir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the conditions in the controller to make sure you have 5 that match your conditions:

```
@orders_outstanding = Order.where(completed_at: nil).where.not(due_date: nil).order("due_date")
```